# How can I distribute a native executable for a Python program?

Tags: python, pyglet

Lately all of my work has been in Python (and Ruby), and I'm in love with those two languages. There are many libraries for game development on Python but the problem I see is that many of those frameworks don't cover the "distribution" aspect of game creation. I'd like to code my game on Python (and any other pure Python extra libraries I need) and be able to distribute an executable for the main PC platforms (Windows, Mac and Linux).

Any options out there or what are the best combinations for this? (maybe pyglet + cx_freeze)

Answer (score 12):

Some Options for Python:

- Multiplatform (Win/Linux/Mac): [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)
- Multiplatform (Win/Linux/Max): [cx-freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)
- Windows: [py2exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/)
- Mac: [py2app](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app)

  The bad news is that, as far as I can tell, you can't create binaries for a platform from another platform.  The reason seems to be dependencies on platform-specific libraries.

  **Edit**: By the way, you might be interested in looking at this [comparison table](http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=tZ42hjaRunvkObFq0bKxVdg&output=html).  The guy was using pyglet too.

Answer (score 4):

py2exe + NSIS works well enough, though it can take some voodoo to figure out the right py2exe config usually (but you only have to do that once). You can also look at setuptools' entry-point-based script generation and the pkg_resources API for working with data files.

Comment: I use this system and found it to be quite useful, if a bit steep on the learning curve.